Google Sheet to JSON app script gives CORS error
I am getting a JSON from Sheet data
using a deployed app script
The JSON data in the browsers looks correct
But when I add the URL to an app called Kumu.io to visually represent the data
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbymN0Wkfl-Lp4n0kD2L1DXmY4BbZhi8CvoB8nW2pguvelXhqAhRo4YQuYquS5Mv_FU/exec?id=12ygFGlEbqosGDj_4VSg6pzTjnHn58XuLAtmMpkdoUzM&sheet=Elements&header=1&startRow=2
I get a CORS error message
Please make sure the url below is valid and CORS is enabled.

How do I enable CORS for this deployed script?
Thanks
Google sheet with data and code
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ygFGlEbqosGDj_4VSg6pzTjnHn58XuLAtmMpkdoUzM/edit?usp=sharing
app script
/**
 * Test the original functionality of returning all objects
 * in the spreadsheet in JSON.
 */
function test1() {
  return runTest_({
      parameters : {
        id : "12ygFGlEbqosGDj_4VSg6pzTjnHn58XuLAtmMpkdoUzM",
        sheet : "Elements",
        header : 1,
        startRow : 2,
      }
  });
}

/**
 * Basic test logs a request and response. Use View -> Logs to check if it's
 * correct.
 * (In the future maybe actually check equality to expected output.)
 * @param request The HTTP request to test
 */
function runTest_(request) {
  console.log(request);
  console.log(doGet(request).getContent().toString());
}

/**
 * Main method is called when the script receives a GET request.
 * Receives the request, generates and returns the output.
 */
function doGet(request) {
  // Get request params.
  var sheetKey  = request.parameters.id;
  var sheetName = request.parameters.sheet;
  var callback  = request.parameters.callback;
  var headerRow = request.parameters.header;
  var startRow  = request.parameters.startRow;
    
  // Parse the spreadsheet.
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetKey);
  var keys = getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName, headerRow);
  var data = readData_(spreadsheet, sheetName, keys, startRow);
  
  // Filter for matching terms.
  data = data.filter(function(entry) {
    var matches = true;
    for (var k in keys) {
      var key = keys[k].replace(/\s+/g, '_');
      var searchTerm = request.parameters[key];
      // Use the string form of the value since params are strings by default
      if (searchTerm != undefined)
        matches = matches && ("" + entry[key] == searchTerm);
    }
    // Matches is true iff all params are undefined or all values for keys match.
    return matches;
  });
  
  // Write and return the response.
  var response = JSON.stringify({ elements: data });
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  if (callback == undefined) {
    // Serve as JSON
    output.setContent(response).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } else {
    // Serve as JSONP
    output.setContent(callback + "(" + response + ")")
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
  }
  return output;
}

/**
 * Get a row in a spreadsheet as an Object, using the values in the header row as
 * keys and the corresponding row values as the values.
 * 
 * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header
 * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet with the data
 * @param properties Optional array of keys to use for the row values. Default is the first row.
 * @param startRowNum Optional top row number of the rows to parse. The default is
 * the second row (i.e., below the header).
 */
function readData_(spreadsheet, sheetName, properties, startRowNum) {
  if (typeof properties == "undefined") {
    properties = getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName);
  }
  
  var rows = getDataRows_(spreadsheet, sheetName, startRowNum);
  var data = [];
  for (var r = 0, l = rows.length-1; r < l; r++) {
    var row = rows[r];
    var record = {};
    for (var p in properties) {
      record[properties[p]] = row[p];
    }
    data.push(record);
  }
  return data;
}

/**
 * Parse spreadsheet data as an array of Javascript Objects.
 *
 * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object with the data to get
 * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet with the data
 * @param startRowNum Optional top row number of the rows to parse. The default is
 * the second row (i.e., below the header).
 */
function getDataRows_(spreadsheet, sheetName, startRowNum) {
  if (typeof startRowNum == "undefined") startRowNum = 2;
  
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet.getRange(startRowNum, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
}

/**
 * Return the array of keys used in the header, replacing whitespace with underscores.
 * 
 * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header
 * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet whose header values to get
 * @param rowNum Optional exact row number of the header. Default is the first row.
 */
function getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum) {
  if (typeof rowNum == "undefined") rowNum = 1;
  return getHeaderRow_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum).map(function(value) { 
    return value.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
  });
}

/**
 * Get the values in the header row of the given sheet in a spreadsheet
 * 
 * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header
 * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet whose header values to get
 * @param rowNum Exact row number of the header.
 */
function getHeaderRow_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum) {
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
}


This is just my guess. From your following situation,

The JSON data in the browsers looks correct
But when I add the URL to an app called Kumu.io to visually represent the data
I get a CORS error message

and, from the result that I accessed your showing URL of Web Apps,
I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to the setting of your Web Apps. So, when I saw the Google Apps Script project of your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that the setting of your Web Apps was as follows.
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }

In this case, in order to access the Web Apps, it is required to log in to Google account. Although I'm not sure about Kumu.io of But when I add the URL to an app called Kumu.io to visually represent the data, I guess that this might be the reason for your current issue.
In this case, please update your Web Apps by the following setting.
Execute as: me

Who has access to the app: Anyone

If you want to modify appsscript.json, please modify it as follows.

From
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }


To
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }



With this modification, your Web Apps can be accessed without logging in to your Google account.
Note:

By the way, when you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

You can see the details of this in my report "Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)".


References:

Web Apps
Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script


Thank you for this. it works perfectly now. Better than I had expected as now I can keep the Google sheet Restricted, I do not have to set it so anyone with a link can access the Google Sheet

@Einarr Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. About your specification, I also agree with it.

I do not understand this part: If you want to modify appsscript.json, please modify it as follows.  The From and the To where would I enter this? Thank you again
